# Issue with Font Rendering using Freetype in OpenGL is not working

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es, freetype

I am facing an issue with font rendering. I am using the tutorial https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/Text-Rendering for this.
I am developing the application in OpenGLESV3.

I have made different shader programs for 3D object drawing, for loading textures and lastly for the font rendering.
I am drawing the fonts after the 3D objects and texture drawing is done.
However the issue is that the font is not seen when i draw using orthographic projection. I am able to only see the 3D objects and texture. (Even though the shaders are different)

when I only draw font only with orthographic projection it is drawing perfectly.

I am sure it is the issue with the settings in projection, but i am unable to figure out the issue.
Can anybody help please ?

Here is the code inside my render loop

```
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)SCR_WIDTH, (GLsizei)SCR_HEIGHT);

/********************************* 3D objects Rendering ********************************************************/
glUseProgram(shaderpgmPoints);
projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camspec.fov), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderpgmPoints, "projection"), 1, false, &projection[0][0]);

view = glm::lookAt(camspec.cameraPos, camspec.cameraPos + camspec.cameraFront, camspec.cameraUp);

glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderpgmPoints, "view"), 1, false, &view[0][0]);

model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderpgmPoints, "model"), 1, false, &model[0][0]);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quadBufferObject);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)64);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, leftlaneBufferObject);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)192);

;
glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 12);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);


glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, rightlaneBufferObject);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)32);

glLineWidth(10.0f);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
glUseProgram(0);
/********************************* 3D objects Rendering -End ********************************************************/


/********************************* Texture Rendering ********************************************************/
glUseProgram(shaderpgmTexture);
glm::mat4 transform = glm::mat4(1.0f);
transform = glm::translate(transform, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderpgmTexture, "transform"), 1, false, &transform[0][0]);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderpgmTexture, "outputTexture"), 1);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, camTexture);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, camTextureBufferObject);
// position attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
// texture coord attribute
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

glDisable(GL_BLEND);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
glUseProgram(0);
/********************************* Texture Rendering - End ********************************************************/

/********************************* Font Rendering ********************************************************/
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glUseProgram(shaderpgmFont);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glm::mat4 project = glm::ortho(0.0f, static_cast<GLfloat>(SCR_WIDTH), 0.0f, static_cast<GLfloat>(SCR_HEIGHT));
glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderpgmFont, "projection"), 1, false, &project[0][0]);
glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderpgmFont, "textColor"), 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
GLfloat scale = 1.0f;
GLfloat x = 10.0f;
GLfloat y = 10.0f;
std::string text = "THE";
std::string::const_iterator c;
for (c = text.begin(); c != text.end(); c++)
{
    Character ch = Characters[*c];

    GLfloat xpos = x + ch.Bearing.x * scale;
    GLfloat ypos = y - (ch.Size.y - ch.Bearing.y) * scale;

    GLfloat w = ch.Size.x * scale;
    GLfloat h = ch.Size.y * scale;
    GLfloat vertices[6][4] = {
        { xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0, 0.0 },
        { xpos,     ypos,       0.0, 1.0 },
        { xpos + w, ypos,       1.0, 1.0 },

        { xpos,     ypos + h,   0.0, 0.0 },
        { xpos + w, ypos,       1.0, 1.0 },
        { xpos + w, ypos + h,   1.0, 0.0 }
    };

    // Render glyph texture over quad
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ch.TextureID);
    // Update content of VBO memory
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, FontVertexBufferObject);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices); // Be sure to use glBufferSubData and not glBufferData
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    // Now advance cursors for next glyph (note that advance is number of 1/64 pixels)
    x += (ch.Advance >> 6) * scale; // Bitshift by 6 to get value in pixels (2^6 = 64 (divide amount of 1/64th pixels by 64 to get amount of pixels))
}

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glUseProgram(0);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
/********************************* Font Rendering - End********************************************************/
```

I am Initializing the font buffer like this

```
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glUseProgram(shaderpgmFont);
// FreeType
FT_Library ft;
// All functions return a value different than 0 whenever an error occurred
if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft))
    std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYPE: Could not init FreeType Library" << std::endl;

// Load font as face
FT_Face face;
if (FT_New_Face(ft, "fonts/arial.ttf", 0, &face))
{
    std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYPE: Failed to load font" << std::endl;
}   
else
{
    // Set size to load glyphs as
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 48);

    // Disable byte-alignment restriction
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    // Load first 128 characters of ASCII set
    for (GLubyte c = 0; c < 128; c++)
    {
        // Load character glyph 
        if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYTPE: Failed to load Glyph" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        // Generate texture
        GLuint texture;
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glTexImage2D(
            GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            GL_ALPHA,
            face->glyph->bitmap.width,
            face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
            0,
            GL_ALPHA,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            face->glyph->bitmap.buffer
        );
        // Set texture options
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        // Now store character for later use
        Character character = {
            texture,
            glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows),
            glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap_left, face->glyph->bitmap_top),
            face->glyph->advance.x
        };
        Characters.insert(std::pair<GLchar, Character>(c, character));
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    // Destroy FreeType once we're finished
    FT_Done_Face(face);
    FT_Done_FreeType(ft);



    // Configure VAO/VBO for texture quads
    glGenBuffers(1, &FontVertexBufferObject);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, FontVertexBufferObject);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6 * 4, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
glUseProgram(0);
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Comment: The question is unclear: you said "with orthographic projection it is drawing perfectly" then later you said "I am sure it is the issue with the settings in projection".

It sounds like you changed something in the code, and the result changed from good to bad.  However it is unclear what you changed.

Comment: Hi, Actually i meant without 3D objects and texture drawing it is working fine. But when I include both of them it is not working.
The order of drawing is 
1) 3D objects
2) Texture
3) Font

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your initialization function, you've set up some OpenGL state via `glVertexAttribPointer`, which later gets clobbered.

To fix this, modify your text-rendering code so that it makes two calls `glVertexAttribPointer` after `glBindBuffer`.

Comment: Hi prideout,
Thank you very much. It worked for both orthographic and perspective projection. 
I need one suggestion, Now i am using single viewport for both ortho and perspective projections, Is it a good practice to have different viewport for them ?

Comment: It's fine to use the same `glViewport`, the only times you need to change the viewport are when the window resizes or if you're drawing multiple 3D views on the screen (e.g. a minimap in a corner).

Comment: That's great.
Thank you prideout. :)